# Unable to generate gpg keys in linux

Tags: linux, gpgpu, gnupg, gpgme

I'm not able to generate GPG keys in linux

```
sudo gpg --gen-key      # This is the command to try to generate key
```

error

```
You need a Passphrase to protect your secret key.

gpg: problem with the agent: Timeout        
gpg: Key generation canceled.
```

Please let me know where I'm doing wrong

Comment: Can you please try without sudo or directly with root login

Comment: gpg with sudo,please try with this command : sudo --preserve-env YOUR_COMMAND...

Comment: @rups thnx for quick reply, when do I execute without sudo I go below error  You need a Passphrase to protect your secret key.

gpg: cancelled by user
gpg: Key generation canceled.

Comment: Have you try with sudo --preserve-env YOUR_COMMAND?

Comment: I got this with above command    sudo --preserve-env gpg --gen-key
sudo: invalid option -- '-'
usage: sudo [-D level] -h | -K | -k | -V
usage: sudo -v [-AknS] [-D level] [-g groupname|#gid] [-p prompt] [-u user name|#uid]

Comment: try with sudo -E YOUR_COMMAND

Comment: @rups i hv tried one more command  sudo -E gpg --gen-key but getting same error   gpg: problem with the agent: Timeout        
gpg: Key generation canceled.

Comment: FWIW I had the same problem and it was because gpg was prompting me for a password via pop up window (forgot about this), but I was sshing into the computer w/o xforwarding at the time.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Please check with this

1) Run the gpg-agent command:

```
gpg-agent --daemon --use-standard-socket --pinentry-program /usr/bin/pinentry-curses
```

2) Generate enough entropy

```
sudo rngd -r /dev/urandom
```

3) Finally run the gpg command to generate the key:

```
gpg --gen-key
```

please run all commands with non-root user only

Please login with same user,which is used to create gpg keys.

1.We will export both our public key and private key as follows:

```
  user$ gpg --export -a -o mypublickey.txt user@replaceurmail.com
  user$ gpg --export-secret-key -a -o myprivatekey.txt user@replaceurmail.com
  user$ ls my*
```

myprivatekey.txt        mypublickey.txt

2. Import keys with same user

   ```
   User$ gpg --import myprivatekey.txt
   ```
3. now try decrypt with same user

Comment: once again thnx... Sm error I got....You need a Passphrase to protect your secret key.

gpg: problem with the agent: Timeout
gpg: Key generation canceled.

Comment: all above command without sudo I got below error...... gpg: cancelled by user
gpg: Key generation canceled.

Comment: have check folder & it permission of ~/.gnupg or please create mkdir -p 700 ~/.gnupg

Comment: again I got same error...You need a Passphrase to protect your secret key.

gpg: problem with the agent: Timeout
gpg: Key generation canceled.

Comment: please check gpg agent running or not with this command : pgrep gpg-agent

Comment: It is running.....[xxxxx@woksmddev01 ~]$ pgrep gpg-agent
31084
31122

Comment: Last try : 1. please kill all process of gpg-agent & clean ~/.gnupg folder then run " eval $(gpg-agent --daemon) "  command. 2 check gpg-agent running or not using "pgrep gpg-agent" command. 3. please run "export GPG_TTY=$(tty)" command & then 4. gpg --gen-key

Comment: @rups...thnx lot man....now problem has been resolved...I have one more concern, I got error(gpg: decryption failed: No secret key)  when do I decrypt the process sudo gpg -d -o xxxxxxx1 xxxxxxx.gpg

Comment: Have you try  without sudo?

Comment: sm error without sudo....gpg: encrypted with RSA key, ID 4273F35C
gpg: decryption failed: No secret key

Comment: what is output of  gpg --list-keys

Comment: the output of above command        /root/.gnupg/pubring.gpg
------------------------
pub   4096R/6197F9FC 2015-03-01
uid                  Akhilesh Chand (akhilesh) <xxxxxxx@gmail.com>
sub   4096R/4273F35C 2015-03-01

pub   2048R/3FA59C97 2015-03-02
uid                  akhilesh (ak) <xxxxx@gmail.com>
sub   2048R/EC0BCE3F 2015-03-02

Comment: thnx a lot rups.......when do i export private key.... sudo gpg --export-secret-key -a -o myprivatekey.txt xxxxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com
gpg: WARNING: nothing exported

Comment: rups problem has been resolved thnx a lot for the same.....

Comment: same problem and it's still running >_<

Comment: I get this warning message when using --use-standard-socket; '''gpg-agent: WARNING: "--use-standard-socket" is an obsolete option - it has no effect'''

Comment: Under Debian to use rngd you need to install rng-tools package.

Comment: `sudo rngd -r /dev/urandom` was the only command needed for me to proceed with a key generation.

Comment: I get this when I run the command 
`gpg-agent[3745]: WARNING: "--use-standard-socket" is an obsolete option - it has no effect
gpg-agent[3745]: directory '/home/vscode/.gnupg/private-keys-v1.d' created
gpg-agent: a gpg-agent is already running - not starting a new one`